# Electron Crashes on Printing - Electron JS

Tags: node.js, printing, electron

So I am using `electron-pos-printer` for sending the data to a thermal printer, but when I click on print, it prints it out but electron crashes, I can't really figure out why. I have also tried printing using the `webContents.print()` method but even that causes electron to crash.

Is there any previous version I can downgrade to that will fix it? Or is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Today 2020.9.29 Electron v10.1.3 has been released with fixing some issues.

Try to upgrade your electron version to the latest stable version.

Below are the release notes

> v10.1.3 electron v10.1.3  Release Notes for v10.1.3
>
> Fixes
>
> Fixed CORS not being disabled by webSecurity: false. #25503 (Also in
> 9, 10, 11)
>
> Fixed ready-to-show event not emitted on some machines. #25476 (Also
> in 9, 10, 11)
>
> Fixed a crash in app.importCertificate() on Linux. #25536 (Also in 9,
> 10, 11)
>
> Fixed a crash when closing window in an event listener after exiting
> fullscreen on macOS. #25604 (Also in 10, 11)
>
> Fixed an issue that could cause a normally-exiting process to fail
> with an "illegal access" message and exit code 7. #25458 (Also in 8,
> 9, 10, 11)
>
> Fixed an issue where an error would be displayed when using
> webContents.print() if no default was set and no device name provided.
> #25606 (Also in 9, 10, 11)
>
> Fixed an issue where multiple calls to window.print() could cause a
> crash. #25530
>
> Fixed an issue where pageRanges was not properly honored when
> printing. #25597 (Also in 10)
>
> Fixed crashes caused by attempting to modify destroyed views. #25511
> (Also in 9, 10, 11)
>
> Fixed the remote-debugging-port discovery page showing garbled text.
> #25601 (Also in 10, 11)
>
> Updated Node root certs to use NSS 3.56. #25361 (Also in 8, 9, 10, 11)
>
> Other Changes
>
> Added a small console hint to console to help debug renderer crashes.
> #25472 (Also in 9, 10, 11)
>
> Fixed resource leak in worker threads. #25662 (Also in 9, 10, 11)
>
> Updated Chromium to 85.0.4183.121. #25559
>
> Unknown
>
> Fixed extension background page devtools not being openable. #25566
> (Also in 9, 10, 11)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Turns out that installing the electron globally causes the crash. Try installing your electron in your local repository. This worked for me!!!